# Qpython OL: type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject in makeIntent()

Tags: python, android-intent, qpython, jsonexception

I am trying to make an intent using `androidhelper` in *Qpython OL* with the code below:

```
action = "org.escpos.intent.action.PRINT"
packagename =  "com.loopedlabs.escposprintservice" #  target application
data = data # convert data to PDF byte array format
extras = {
         'DATA_TYPE':'PDF',
        'PDF_DATA' : data # raw PDF data
}
intent = droid.makeIntent( # make an intent
    action = action,
    packagename = packagename,
    extras = extras
)
```

But I am having the following Error:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value [2,{"extras":{"DATA_TYPE":"PDF","PDF_DATA":"4"},"categories":null,"action":"org.escpos.intent.action.PRINT","flags":268435456},null] at 0 of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Additionally, I did not find any working example of `android.makeIntent()`. Could somebody help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something went wrong in `extras`.
What's your `data`? Are you sure it can be called in this way?

Here's a working `makeIntent` example. This works on my phone:

```
#-*-coding:utf8;-*-
#qpy:2
#qpy:console

from androidhelper import Android
droid = Android()
uri2open = "https://google.com"
intent2start = droid.makeIntent("android.intent.action.VIEW", uri2open, "text/html", None, [u"android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"], None, None, None)
print(droid.startActivityForResultIntent(intent2start.result))
```